# Trouble with InstaFeed (search) and jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, jquery-mobile

I'm new to development and I'm trying to finish my first JQM site. However my search input form requires a manual page refresh after submission before the instafeed photos will show up. I can't get it to work no matter what I try. I've also found that when I remove JQM from loading, it works just fine. Why does every version of JQM break my **search**?  Everything works perfectly on the desktop version of the site.

http://www.instacuteness.com/mobile/

Here is my code on jsfiddle:

```
www.jsfiddle.net/xS8eY/4/
```

Can someone please help!

Comment: Pls post your code, or reproduce the problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It works on iPad without refresh. However you have a problem width JQM icons you need to place JQM icons under `/images/` where you have JQM CSS file.

Comment: I fixed the JQM icons and just added it to jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xS8eY/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial page has id `index`. When you submit the form, a second page is created in DOM with the same id `index`. The result is that you have the same page in DOM, more than once.

So even if the `instafeed` script is executed, it feeds with photos the first page which is hidden and not the active page which is shown on the screen.

Add the following script inside the `<div data-role="page" id="index">`

```
$(document).on('pagehide', '#index', function(event, ui){
    $(event.target).remove();
});
```

This `script` will remove the last page from DOM. However note that there are more elegant solutions.

At last jQuery Mobile 1.2 supports up to version jQuery core 1.8.2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Instacuteness: The Cutest Animals on Instagram, Viewable on the Web!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="instafeed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('#nospace').bind('keyup', function(){
                  var value = $(this).val()
                  $(this).val(value.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
                });
            });
        </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getUrlVars() {
                var vars = {};
                var parts = (($(this).data("url") && $(this).data("url").indexOf("?") > 0) 
                                ? $(this).data("url") 
                                : window.location.href ).replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
                    vars[key] = value;
                });
                return vars;
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('pagehide', '#index', function(event, ui){
                $(event.target).remove();
            }); 
            function goToPage()
            {
                var initial = "http://www.instacuteness.com/mobile/";
                $("#test").attr("href", initial+url);
                window.location(initial+url);
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).one('pageshow', '#index', function() {
                var urlParams = getUrlVars();
                var tag = typeof urlParams["id"] === 'undefined' ? 'pets' : urlParams["id"];
                //console.log(tag);
                var feed = new Instafeed({
                    get: 'tagged',
                    tagName: tag,
                    clientId: '3d0a5cba5a524ff7bf81d100c382ab40',
                    template: '<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /><\/a>',
                    resolution: 'low_resolution',
                    limit: '60'
                });
                feed.run();             
            });
        </script>

        <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <form action="" class="form-search" id="input" name="input">
                    <input id="nospace" name="id" placeholder="Search for a tag..." type="text"
                    value="">
                </form>
            </div><br>
        </header>

        <div data-role="content">
            <p><img src="Images/logo.png"></p>

            <p><a data-role="button" data-theme="a" href="#about">About Instacuteness</a></p>
        </div>

        <div data-collapsed="true" data-collapsed-icon="plus" data-expanded-icon="minus" data-role=
        "collapsible">
            <h3>Choose a Tag</h3>

            <p></p>

            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=pets" rel="external">All Pets</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=puppy" rel="external">Puppy</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=kitten" rel="external">Kitten</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=bunny" rel="external">Bunny</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=horse" rel="external">Horse</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=parrot" rel="external">Parrot</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=giraffe" rel="external">Giraffe</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=kangaroo" rel="external">Kangaroo</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=koala" rel="external">Koala</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=panda" rel="external">Panda</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=lion" rel="external">Lion</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=tiger" rel="external">Tiger</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=bear" rel="external">Bear</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=elephant" rel="external">Elephant</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=hippo" rel="external">Hippo</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=zebra" rel="external">Zebra</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=fox" rel="external">Fox</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=cow" rel="external">Cow</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=owl" rel="external">Owl</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=deer" rel="external">Deer</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=penguin" rel="external">Penguin</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="index.html?id=clownfish" rel="external">Clownfish</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <p></p>
        </div><br>

        <div id="instafeed"></div><br>

        <footer data-role="footer">
            <h2>© footer here.</h2>
        </footer>

    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="about">
        <header data-role="header">
            <h1>About Instacuteness</h1>
        </header>

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Instacuteness is an open-source project coded by Katy Marques. Instacuteness
            integrates the most recently tagged animal pictures on Instagram in order for you to
            view them on the web. There are several popular tags on the home page that are viewable
            with a single click, or you can use the handy search box to see photos of any tag that
            you'd like!</p><a href="https://github.com/KatyAverill"><img src="Images/Octocat.png"
            width="200px">

            <div class="caption">
                Click here to check out my GitHub!
            </div><br></a><br>

            <p>Head <a data-rel="back" href="#index">back</a> to Instacuteness.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-42028707-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'instacuteness.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much-that resolved the issue of the duplicate page stored in DOM.  However, it's now showing the photos from the previous search instead the search executed.  Do you have any idea of how to fix that issue?

Comment: You're welcome :) Hmm, let me check and I will update my post

Comment: Hi, I've updated the posted HTML in my answer with a workaround for updating the photos. Basically, the first page's `scripts` are modified. Could you check if it works for you?